# install fuelphp 403 error

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have downloaded fuel unzipped it and placed it in a virtual host(virtual hostX) it comes up as fuel.site
but not the welcome page it just comes up a directory listing

```
changelog.md
docs(folder)
oil
```

if I try and go manually to the public folder I get a 403 error
what do I need to configure to get it to run?

I even tried a `.htaccess` file with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /fuel/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fuel/public/public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in it as recommended on another site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys i had some errors in my apache setup using mamp now working fine thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the answer here: http://docs.fuelphp.com/installation/instructions.html#manual

Could you show me the dir/filestructure? The public/public seems a bit off. And the rewrite base should probably just be /. Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fuel/public/index.php/$1 [L]
    # Sometimes it's: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fuel/public/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```